# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm developing a discord.js moderation bot, but when I run it I get this error.

[image]

Here is the code:

````js
var Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require("fs")
const { PREFIX } = require("../../config")
const db = require('quick.db')
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");

module.exports = {
config: {
    name: "help",
    description: "Help Menu",
    usage: "1) m/help \n2) m/help [module name]\n3) m/help [command (name or alias)]",
    example: "1) m/help\n2) m/help utility\n3) m/help ban",
    aliases: ['h']
},
run: async (bot, message, args) => {
    let prefix;
    if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;
        try {
            let fetched = await db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`);
            if (fetched == null) {
                prefix = PREFIX
            } else {
                prefix = fetched
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
    };

if(message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}help`){
    var log = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("**Help Menu: Main**")
    .setColor(`#d9d9d9`)
    .addField(`**Moderation**`, `[ \`${prefix}help mod\` ]`, true)
    .addField(`**⚙️Utility**`, `[ \`${prefix}help utility\` ]`, true)

message.channel.send(log);
} 
else if(args[0].toLowerCase() === "mod") {
    var commandArray = "1) Ban \n2) Kick\n3) Whois\n4) Unban\n5) Warn\n6) Mute\n7) Purge\n8) Slowmode \n9) Nick \n10) Roleinfo"
    var commandA2 = "11) Rolememberinfo\n12) Setmodlog\n13) Disablemodlog\n14) Lock (Lock the channel)\n15) Unlock (Unlock the channel)\n16) Lockdown (Fully Lock the whole server. [FOR EMRGENCIES ONLY]) \n17) Hackban\\forceban <id>"
    
    pageN1 = "**\nCommands: **\n`\`\`js\n" + commandArray + "\`\`\`";
    pageN2 = "**\nCommands: **\n`\`\`js\n" + commandA2 + "\`\`\`";
    
    let pages = [pageN1, pageN2]
    let page = 1 

    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('**Help Menu: [Moderation]**')
        .setColor("#d9d9d9") // Set the color
        .setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(pages[page-1])

        message.channel.send({embed}).then(msg => {
            msg.react('⬅').then( r => {
            msg.react('➡')
            
            // Filters
            const backwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⬅' && user.id === message.author.id
            const forwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡' && user.id === message.author.id
            
            const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(backwardsFilter, {timer: 6000})
            const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(forwardsFilter, {timer: 6000})
            
            backwards.on('collect', (r, u) => {
                if (page === 1) return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
                page--
                embed.setDescription(pages[page-1])
                embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
                msg.edit(embed)
                r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
            })
            
            forwards.on('collect', (r, u) => {
                if (page === pages.length) return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
                page++
                embed.setDescription(pages[page-1])
                embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
                msg.edit(embed)
                r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
            })
            
            
            })
            })
}

else if(args[0].toLowerCase() === "util") {
    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('**Help Menu: [Utility]**')
    .setColor("#d9d9d9") // Set the color
    .setDescription("```js" + `1) Prefix [${prefix}help prefix for more info]\n 2) Help [${prefix}help for more info]` + "```")
} else {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#d9d9d9")
    .setAuthor(`${message.guild.me.displayName} Help`, message.guild.iconURL())
    .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())

    let command = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || args[0].toLowerCase())
    if (!command) return message.channel.send(embed.setTitle("**Invalid Command!**").setDescription(`**Do \`${prefix}help\` For the List Of the Commands!**`))
    command = command.config

    embed.setDescription(stripIndents`
    ** Command -** [    \`${command.name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + command.name.slice(1)}\`   ]\n
    ** Description -** [    \`${command.description || "No Description provided."}\`   ]\n
    ** Usage -** [   \`${command.usage ? `\`${command.usage}\`` : "No Usage"}\`   ]\n
    ** Examples -** [   \`${command.example ? `\`${command.example}\`` : "No Examples Found"}\`   ]\n
    ** Aliases -** [   \`${command.aliases ? command.aliases.join(" , ") : "None."}\`   ]`)
    embed.setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())

    return message.channel.send(embed)
}

    

}

}
````

If someone could help with this issue it would be great because I don't know what to do. I already searched on internet but I still don't know what I need to do to solve this error. All this code is for help function, when someone calls -pks help the bot should show embed telling all his functions

Here is my index.js file:

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { PREFIX, TOKEN } = require('./config');
const bot = new Client({ disableMentions: 'everyone' });
const fs = require("fs");
const db = require('quick.db');

bot.commands = new Collection();
bot.aliases = new Collection();

["aliases", "commands"].forEach(x => bot[x] = new Collection());
["console", "command", "event"].forEach(x => require(`./handler/${x}`)(bot));

bot.categories = fs.readdirSync("./commands/");

["command"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handler/${handler}`)(bot);
});

bot.on('message', async message => {
    let prefix;
        try {
            let fetched = await db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`);
            if (fetched == null) {
                prefix = PREFIX
            } else {
                prefix = fetched
            }
        
            } catch {
            prefix = PREFIX
    };
    try {
        if (message.mentions.has(bot.user.id) && !message.content.includes("@everyone") && !message.content.includes("@here")) {
          message.channel.send(`\nMy prefix for \`${message.guild.name}\` is \`${prefix}\` Type \`${prefix}help\` for help`);
          }
          
    } catch {
        return;
    };
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: `args[0]` is undefined, as the error says - maybe there are no arguments in your message?

Comment: There are 2 problems I have for you: you are not using args; you are not executing it properly

Comment: `args` is being passed in through `run: async(...)`, and how are they not properly executing it?

Comment: Im excuting it with node index.js

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). There is nothing in that error message that isn't text, and that text can be copied and pasted directly into your question. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate the problem or issue.

Comment: Ok, but what can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Can you show your `index.js` where you execute this function?

Comment: Any Idea of what to do?

Comment: So where do you execute your command?

Comment: I excuted the command in the index.js file

Comment: I already fixed the problem I just changed the prefix to $ instead of -pks and it worked now I can use the bot.

Comment: Idk how it fixed your problem but there can't be an error in the prefix, it can still be a problem if someone just runs command without any arguments provided